# Why does my R run in dynamic scoping? Shouldn't it be lexical?

Tags: r, dynamic, scoping, lexical

I just learned in class that R uses lexical scoping, and tested it out in R Studio on my computer and I got results that fit dynamic scoping, not lexical? Isn't that not supposed to happen in R? I ran:

```
y <- 10
f <- function(x) {
  y <- 2
  y^3
}
f(3)
```

And f(3) came out to be 4 (2^3) not 100 (10^3), even though my class presented this slide: http://puu.sh/pStxA/0545079dbe.png . Isn't that dynamic scoping? I may just be looking at this wrong, but is there a mode on a menu somewhere where you can switch the scoping to lexical, or what is happening?

Comment: You should work on formatting your question and on making it internally consistent. (You use cubed in your code example and sqaured in your paragraph.) Also, you may be using RStudio as a code editor, but this question is about R, not RStudio. You wouldn't tag an English grammar question with "Word" just because you were using MS Word as your editor.

Comment: 2^3 is 4??? 10^3 is 100??? Fortunately for my sanity R doesn't think so either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has assigned y within the function itself, which is looked up before the y in the global environment.

From this excellent article (http://www.r-bloggers.com/environments-in-r/): "When a function is evaluated, R looks in a series of environments for any variables in scope. The evaluation environment is first, then the function’s enclosing environment, which will be the global environment for functions defined in the workspace."

In simpler language specific to your case: when you call the variable "y", R looks for "y" in the function's environment, and if it fails to find one, then it goes to your workspace. An example to illustrate:

```
y <- 10

f <- function(x) {
  y^3
}

f(3)
```

Will produce output:

```
> f(3)
[1] 1000
```

Comment: Also note that defining y in the function does not reach the global scope unless you use the `<<-` assignment operator instead of `<-`

Comment: Okay. So I thought that too, but my lesson has this slide: http://puu.sh/pStxA/0545079dbe.png Is this just incorrect then?

Comment: Quoting this source (https://github.com/jtleek/modules/blob/master/02_RProgramming/Scoping/index.md): 

"Lexical scoping in R means that

The values of FREE (emphasis mine) variables are searched for in the environment in which the function was defined."

In your case, y was not a free variable because you assigned y <- 2 inside the function's environment.

Comment: Hm oh okay. I guess this class just presented a bad example then? Bad as in doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have access to the full lecture notes: it seems to me that the first part about lexical scoping might be referring to a different example, in which y was a "free variable"?

Comment: Well sadly both lexical scoping and dynamic scoping parts are referring to this example: http://puu.sh/pSuQl/80f52cc50d.png which I feel is similar to what I ran. So in this instance, this is because y is not a free variable, and R is running in lexical scoping?

Comment: Thank you btw for answering! I was very confused

Comment: The console prints 34. 

The reason for it is like this: both f and g are functions in the global environment. In f, y is NOT a free variable. In g, y is a free variable. So when you call f(3), the calculations go thus: 

y = 2; y^2 = 4. g(3) is called, which takes 3*y. It cannot find y inside the function g, so it looks for y in the global environment, which has a value of 10. Therefore, g(3) produces 30. 30+4 = 34.

Comment: No problems, and welcome to StackOverflow. You should also look at the guidelines for asking questions for your future questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask